# Submitting a form within script tags

Tags: jquery, html, .net

Hi I have a form inside script tags. When I submit save button it doesnt do anything. The code is

```
 <script id="e1" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    <form id="MainForm" >
           <input type="hidden" id="id1" name="id1" value=""/>
        <table  class="form-i" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
           <tbody>
                 <tr class="form-list">
                      <td>{{=MainLoc}}</td>
                      <td>{{=locId}}</td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="main_form" id="mainLoc" name="mainLoc"    value=""/></td>

            </tr>      
             <tr>
               <td colspan="1" align="center">
                  <br/>
               </td>               
            </tr>           
                </tbody>           
        </table> 
              <input type="button" class="form-submit" onclick="fnSave()"  value="Save"/>        
    </form>
</script>
```

When I hit the save button it doesnt work. When I remove the script tags it works fine. But I have to use script tags because of some other functionality. Please help let me know hot to fix this.
Thanks

Comment: where is your `fnSave()` function?

Comment: Enclosing HTML inside a `<script>` tag is not a valid construction in HTML or Javascript. Why would you think this will work? It can't be fixed in its current form.

Comment: fnSave() is where it writes to the database. Problem is on click the function is not called.

Comment: @Mike the script is a template. I suppose it gets inserted in DOM by some templating library.

Answer (score 1):

After inserting the template in DOM, create the event listener manually:

`$('#e1 button.form-submit').click(fnSave);`

Do you know if your site has any [CSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) rules that are disabling inline stuff?
Any console output?

Answer (score 0):

What is the other function you are using that means the form has to be in script tags?
If you want to access the form, using $('form#e1') should suffice?